# Count all columns with a specific name aggregated by date in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

So I have this simple aggregate function that uses the `date_trunc` method to give me the desired level of precision, but I need to to include the sum of columns with certain criteria in my aggregation.

To give you an idea of what I want

```
SELECT
     COUNT( comments )
    ,COUNT( likes )
    ,COUNT( something_else )
    ,date_trunc( 'minute' ,date )
FROM
    events
GROUP BY
    date_trunc( 'minute' ,date );
```

Where `comments`, `likes` and `something_else` would be a derived table of events where the column `name = commnt` (thats the part I need help with)

EDIT

sample table and desired output

```
____________________
|  date  |  type   |
|2015-6-1|  post   |
|2015-6-1| comment |
|2015-6-2| comment |
|2015-6-2|  post   |
|2015-6-2|   pm    |
|2015-6-2| comment |
|2015-6-3|   pm    |
```

Should output

```
|  date  |  num_post   |  num_comment  |   num_pm   |
|2015-6-1|     1       |      1        |      0     |
|2015-6-2|     1       |      2        |      1     |
|2015-6-3|     0       |      0        |      1     |
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. Maybe include an example table and what you want the output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a table of test data matching yours:

```
   event    |  type   
------------+---------
 2015-06-01 | comment
 2015-06-01 | post
 2015-06-02 | comment
 2015-06-02 | comment
 2015-06-02 | pm
 2015-06-02 | post
 2015-06-03 | pm
(7 rows)
```

And then running

```
  select event, sum((type='post')::int) as posts,
                sum((type='comment')::int) as comments,
                sum((type='pm')::int) as pms
    from exp
group by event
order by event
```

gets me

```
   event    | posts | comments | pms 
------------+-------+----------+-----
 2015-06-01 |     1 |        1 |   0
 2015-06-02 |     1 |        2 |   1
 2015-06-03 |     0 |        0 |   1
(3 rows)
```

We get a bunch of booleans from the `type = ...` comparisons, and casting them to int gets us 0's for false, and 1's for trues, which we can then just sum up to get the answers you're looking for.